# How to update C# wpf ComboBox from Socket.BeginRecieve?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, data-binding, combobox

I have a wpf ComboBox databound to an ObservableCollection that needs to be updated from an asynchronous function BeginRecieve, in the Socket class.  I know that when the async function is executed it is in a new thread and you cannot update the main GUI controls through other threads.  Can someone please give me a example of how this might be accomplished?

Your help is much appreciated thanks.

Comment: Use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().  Type it in the Search box.

Comment: @Hans Passant, actually Invoke is better than BeginInvoke for this kind of scenario. Using BeginInvoke can result in synchronization issues, I learned it the hard way...

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the contents of the collection from another thread, you need to do it on the dispatcher thread. So, instead of this:

```
collection.Add(item);
```

Do this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => collection.Add(item)));
```

Another option is to use a collection that raises the `CollectionChanged` event on the dispatcher thread. I posted an example [here](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/).